# Node-SSPI error 401 with Safari

Tags: ios, node.js, safari

We're trying to use the [node-sspi](https://github.com/abbr/NodeSSPI) package to provide Authentication for our in-house website, linking into the Domain Active Directory.

Running the example code we can authenticate from Windows machines directly, and on Safari (Mac OS X and iOS) we are challenged for credentials, as expected.

However, when we move the authentication to our backend (Node / express server running on different port to front end) we run into trouble.

The Windows machines continue to respond correctly. Domain based machines single sign on and non-domain machines challenge. During the login process the authentication process is called 3 times, and produces 2(no) 401 responses.

Safari does not challenge for a username or password. The authentication routine is called 2 times, and only one 401 error is returned.

Chrome on iOS and Mac OS X properly works and challenges for log in.

Any suggestions where to look / what to try?